# Exchange Auth breaks when no local GC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I ran into a problem while installing our `Exchange 2010` server where client access authentication does not work unless the server is configured as a domain controller with `global catalogue`.

I went to production with this because of time constraints but I really need to fix it now. I have no idea where the problem could be or how to identify the problem.

My question(s) is(are):

> What could cause this issue? How could I test it and repair it?

I don't really know what information would be relevant to the issue but;

Server OS is `Win 2008 R2` and all DCs are the same.
Exchange server has `CAS`, `Hub Transport` and `Mailbox Server` roles.
External mail is received by another exchange 2010 server running the Edge role in the DMZ. (this works okay and Edge server is not a DC... obviously ;) )

**Please let me know what additional information could be added to improve this question. I will add it as soon as I can.**

This is a follow-on question from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/477486/demoting-a-dc-which-also-runs-exchange-2010).

---

### dcsdiag /v

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   * Verifying that the local machine DC2, is a Directory Server. 
   Home Server = DC2
   * Connecting to directory service on server DC2.
   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Collecting AD specific global data 
   * Collecting site info.
   Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectCategory=ntDSSiteSettings),.......
   The previous call succeeded 
   Iterating through the sites 
   Looking at base site object: CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
   Getting ISTG and options for the site
   * Identifying all servers.
   Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectClass=ntDSDsa),.......
   The previous call succeeded....
   The previous call succeeded
   Iterating through the list of servers 
   Getting information for the server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain 
   objectGuid obtained
   InvocationID obtained
   dnsHostname obtained
   site info obtained
   All the info for the server collected
   Getting information for the server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC3,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain 
   objectGuid obtained
   InvocationID obtained
   dnsHostname obtained
   site info obtained
   All the info for the server collected
   Getting information for the server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=MX1,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain 
   objectGuid obtained
   InvocationID obtained
   dnsHostname obtained
   site info obtained
   All the info for the server collected
   * Identifying all NC cross-refs.
   * Found 3 DC(s). Testing 1 of them.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Brisbane\DC2
      Starting test: Connectivity
         * Active Directory LDAP Services Check
         Determining IP4 connectivity 
         * Active Directory RPC Services Check
         ......................... DC2 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Brisbane\DC2
      Starting test: Advertising
         The DC DC2 is advertising itself as a DC and having a DS.
         The DC DC2 is advertising as an LDAP server
         The DC DC2 is advertising as having a writeable directory
         The DC DC2 is advertising as a Key Distribution Center
         The DC DC2 is advertising as a time server
         The DS DC2 is advertising as a GC.
         ......................... DC2 passed test Advertising
      Test omitted by user request: CheckSecurityError
      Test omitted by user request: CutoffServers
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         * The File Replication Service Event log test 
         Skip the test because the server is running DFSR.
         ......................... DC2 passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         The DFS Replication Event Log. 
         ......................... DC2 passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         * The File Replication Service SYSVOL ready test 
         File Replication Service's SYSVOL is ready 
         ......................... DC2 passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         * The KCC Event log test
         Found no KCC errors in "Directory Service" Event log in the last 15 minutes.
         ......................... DC2 passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         Role Schema Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         Role Domain Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         Role PDC Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         Role Rid Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         Role Infrastructure Update Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         ......................... DC2 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         Checking machine account for DC DC2 on DC DC2.
         * SPN found :LDAP/DC2.corp.domain/corp.domain
         * SPN found :LDAP/DC2.corp.domain
         * SPN found :LDAP/DC2
         * SPN found :LDAP/DC2.corp.domain/corpdomain
         * SPN found :LDAP/ef6459ec-28d5-4ab4-85bc-778547782ce7._msdcs.corp.domain
         * SPN found :E3514235-4B06-11D1-AB04-00C04FC2DCD2/ef6459ec-28d5-4ab4-85bc-778547782ce7/corp.domain
         * SPN found :HOST/DC2.corp.domain/corp.domain
         * SPN found :HOST/DC2.corp.domain
         * SPN found :HOST/DC2
         * SPN found :HOST/DC2.corp.domain/corpdomain
         * SPN found :GC/DC2.corp.domain/corp.domain
         ......................... DC2 passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         * Security Permissions check for all NC's on DC DC2.
         * Security Permissions Check for
           DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
            (NDNC,Version 3)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
            (NDNC,Version 3)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
            (Schema,Version 3)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
            (Configuration,Version 3)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           DC=corp,DC=domain
            (Domain,Version 3)
         ......................... DC2 passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         * Network Logons Privileges Check
         Verified share \\DC2\netlogon
         Verified share \\DC2\sysvol
         ......................... DC2 passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         DC2 is in domain DC=corp,DC=domain
         Checking for CN=DC2,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=corp,DC=domain in domain DC=corp,DC=domain on 1 servers
            Object is up-to-date on all servers.
         Checking for CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain in domain CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain on 1 servers
            Object is up-to-date on all servers.
         ......................... DC2 passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Test omitted by user request: OutboundSecureChannels
      Starting test: Replications
         * Replications Check
         * Replication Latency Check
            DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
               Latency information for 1 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  1 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
               Latency information for 1 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  1 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
               Latency information for 1 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  1 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
               Latency information for 1 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  1 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            DC=corp,DC=domain
               Latency information for 1 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  1 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
         ......................... DC2 passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         * Available RID Pool for the Domain is 3102 to 1073741823
         * DC2.corp.domain is the RID Master
         * DsBind with RID Master was successful
         * rIDAllocationPool is 1602 to 2101
         * rIDPreviousAllocationPool is 1602 to 2101
         * rIDNextRID: 1818
         ......................... DC2 passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         * Checking Service: EventSystem
         * Checking Service: RpcSs
         * Checking Service: NTDS
         * Checking Service: DnsCache
         * Checking Service: DFSR
         * Checking Service: IsmServ
         * Checking Service: kdc
         * Checking Service: SamSs
         * Checking Service: LanmanServer
         * Checking Service: LanmanWorkstation
         * Checking Service: w32time
         * Checking Service: NETLOGON
         ......................... DC2 passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         * The System Event log test
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000003
            Time Generated: 03/19/2013   13:15:51
            Event String:
            A Kerberos Error Message was received:
             on logon session 
             Client Time: 
             Server Time: 3:15:51.0000 3/19/2013 Z
             Error Code: 0xd KDC_ERR_BADOPTION
             Extended Error: 0xc00000bb KLIN(0)
             Client Realm: 
             Client Name: 
             Server Realm: CORP.domain
             Server Name: dc2$@CORP.domain
             Target Name: dc2$@CORP.domain@CORP.domain
             Error Text: 
             File: 9
             Line: f09
             Error Data is in record data.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000003
            Time Generated: 03/19/2013   13:30:51
            Event String:
            A Kerberos Error Message was received:
             on logon session 
             Client Time: 
             Server Time: 3:30:51.0000 3/19/2013 Z
             Error Code: 0xd KDC_ERR_BADOPTION
             Extended Error: 0xc00000bb KLIN(0)
             Client Realm: 
             Client Name: 
             Server Realm: CORP.domain
             Server Name: dc2$@CORP.domain
             Target Name: dc2$@CORP.domain@CORP.domain
             Error Text: 
             File: 9
             Line: f09
             Error Data is in record data.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000003
            Time Generated: 03/19/2013   13:45:52
            Event String:
            A Kerberos Error Message was received:
             on logon session 
             Client Time: 
             Server Time: 3:45:52.0000 3/19/2013 Z
             Error Code: 0xd KDC_ERR_BADOPTION
             Extended Error: 0xc00000bb KLIN(0)
             Client Realm: 
             Client Name: 
             Server Realm: CORP.domain
             Server Name: dc2$@CORP.domain
             Target Name: dc2$@CORP.domain@CORP.domain
             Error Text: 
             File: 9
             Line: f09
             Error Data is in record data.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000003
            Time Generated: 03/19/2013   13:53:46
            Event String:
            A Kerberos Error Message was received:
             on logon session 
             Client Time: 
             Server Time: 3:53:46.0000 3/19/2013 Z
             Error Code: 0x29 KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED
             Extended Error: 
             Client Realm: 
             Client Name: 
             Server Realm: CORP.domain
             Server Name: dc2$
             Target Name: 
             Error Text: 
             File: 3
             Line: 576
             Error Data is in record data.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000003
            Time Generated: 03/19/2013   14:00:52
            Event String:
            A Kerberos Error Message was received:
             on logon session 
             Client Time: 
             Server Time: 4:0:52.0000 3/19/2013 Z
             Error Code: 0xd KDC_ERR_BADOPTION
             Extended Error: 0xc00000bb KLIN(0)
             Client Realm: 
             Client Name: 
             Server Realm: CORP.domain
             Server Name: dc2$@CORP.domain
             Target Name: dc2$@CORP.domain@CORP.domain
             Error Text: 
             File: 9
             Line: f09
             Error Data is in record data.
         ......................... DC2 failed test SystemLog
      Test omitted by user request: Topology
      Test omitted by user request: VerifyEnterpriseReferences
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         The system object reference (serverReference)
         CN=DC2,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=corp,DC=domain and
         backlink on
         CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         are correct. 
         The system object reference (serverReferenceBL)
         CN=DC2,CN=Topology,CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-GlobalSettings,CN=System,DC=corp,DC=domain
         and backlink on
         CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Brisbane,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
         are correct. 
         The system object reference (msDFSR-ComputerReferenceBL)
         CN=DC2,CN=Topology,CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-GlobalSettings,CN=System,DC=corp,DC=domain
         and backlink on
         CN=DC2,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=corp,DC=domain are
         correct. 
         ......................... DC2 passed test VerifyReferences
      Test omitted by user request: VerifyReplicas

      Test omitted by user request: DNS
      Test omitted by user request: DNS

   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : corp
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... corp passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... corp passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : corp.domain
      Test omitted by user request: DNS
      Test omitted by user request: DNS
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         GC Name: \\DC2.corp.domain
         Locator Flags: 0xe00031fd
         PDC Name: \\DC2.corp.domain
         Locator Flags: 0xe00031fd
         Time Server Name: \\DC2.corp.domain
         Locator Flags: 0xe00031fd
         Preferred Time Server Name: \\DC2.corp.domain
         Locator Flags: 0xe00031fd
         KDC Name: \\DC2.corp.domain
         Locator Flags: 0xe00031fd
         ......................... corp.domain passed test
         LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         Skipping site Brisbane, this site is outside the scope provided by the
         command line arguments provided. 
         ......................... corp.domain passed test Intersite
```

---

### dcsdiag /test:topology

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = DC2
   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Brisbane\DC2
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... DC2 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Brisbane\DC2
      Starting test: Topology
         ......................... DC2 passed test Topology


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : Schema

   Running partition tests on : Configuration

   Running partition tests on : corp

   Running enterprise tests on : corp.domain
```

---

### dcsdiag /test:replications

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = DC2
   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Brisbane\DC2
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... DC2 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Brisbane\DC2
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... DC2 passed test Replications


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : Schema

   Running partition tests on : Configuration

   Running partition tests on : corp

   Running enterprise tests on : corp.domain
```

---

### dnslint /ad 10.1.1.21 /s 10.1.1.21

```
DNSLint Report

System Date: Tue Mar 19 14:43:20 2013 

Command run: 

c:\dnslint\dnslint /ad 10.1.1.21 /s 10.1.1.21

Root of Active Directory Forest: 

    corp.domain

Active Directory Forest Replication GUIDs Found:

DC: DC2
GUID: ef6459ec-28d5-4ab4-85bc-778547782ce7

DC: DC3
GUID: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346

DC: MX1
GUID: 579be28b-006e-4f1c-911a-780458c5d081


Total GUIDs found: 3

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following 2 DNS servers were checked for records related to AD forest replication:

DNS server: dc2.corp.domain
IP Address: 10.1.1.21
UDP port 53 responding to queries: YES
TCP port 53 responding to queries: Not tested
Answering authoritatively for domain: YES

SOA record data from server:
Authoritative name server: dc2.corp.domain
Hostmaster: hostmaster.corp.domain
Zone serial number: 150
Zone expires in: 1.00 day(s)
Refresh period: 900 seconds
Retry delay: 600 seconds
Default (minimum) TTL: 3600 seconds


Additional authoritative (NS) records from server:
dc2.corp.domain Unknown
dc3.corp.domain Unknown




Alias (CNAME) and glue (A) records for forest GUIDs from server:
CNAME: ef6459ec-28d5-4ab4-85bc-778547782ce7._msdcs.corp.domain
Alias: dc2.corp.domain
Glue: 10.1.1.21

CNAME: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346._msdcs.corp.domain
Alias: dc3.corp.domain
Glue: 10.1.1.22

CNAME: 579be28b-006e-4f1c-911a-780458c5d081._msdcs.corp.domain
Alias: mx1.corp.domain
Glue: 10.1.1.25


Total number of CNAME records found on this server: 3

Total number of CNAME records missing on this server: 0

Total number of glue (A) records this server could not find: 0



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DNS server: dc3.corp.domain
IP Address: 10.1.1.22
UDP port 53 responding to queries: YES
TCP port 53 responding to queries: Not tested
Answering authoritatively for domain: YES

SOA record data from server:
Authoritative name server: dc3.corp.domain
Hostmaster: hostmaster.corp.domain
Zone serial number: 150
Zone expires in: 1.00 day(s)
Refresh period: 900 seconds
Retry delay: 600 seconds
Default (minimum) TTL: 3600 seconds


Additional authoritative (NS) records from server:
dc2.corp.domain Unknown
dc3.corp.domain Unknown




Alias (CNAME) and glue (A) records for forest GUIDs from server:
CNAME: ef6459ec-28d5-4ab4-85bc-778547782ce7._msdcs.corp.domain
Alias: dc2.corp.domain
Glue: 10.1.1.21

CNAME: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346._msdcs.corp.domain
Alias: dc3.corp.domain
Glue: 10.1.1.22

CNAME: 579be28b-006e-4f1c-911a-780458c5d081._msdcs.corp.domain
Alias: mx1.corp.domain
Glue: 10.1.1.25


Total number of CNAME records found on this server: 3

Total number of CNAME records missing on this server: 0
```

---

### dnscmd /zoneinfo corp.domain

```
Zone query result:

Zone info:
    ptr                   = 0000000000197AB0
    zone name             = corp.domain
    zone type             = 1
    shutdown              = 0
    paused                = 0
    update                = 2
    DS integrated         = 1
    read only zone        = 0
    in DS loading queue   = 0
    currently DS loading  = 0
    data file             = (null)
    using WINS            = 0
    using Nbstat          = 0
    aging                 = 0
      refresh interval    = 168
      no refresh          = 168
      scavenge available  = 0
    Zone Masters    NULL IP Array.
    Zone Secondaries    NULL IP Array.
    secure secs           = 1
    directory partition   = AD-Domain     flags 00000015
    zone DN               = DC=corp.domain,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
Command completed successfully.
```

---

### repadmin /showrepl

```
Repadmin: running command /showrepl against full DC localhost
Brisbane\DC2
DSA Options: IS_GC 
Site Options: (none)
DSA object GUID: ef6459ec-28d5-4ab4-85bc-778547782ce7
DSA invocationID: d2eb9fee-f5ee-458d-b37f-813d6cc41d9b

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=corp,DC=domain
    Brisbane\MX1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 579be28b-006e-4f1c-911a-780458c5d081
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:58:35 was successful.
    Brisbane\DC3 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:59:08 was successful.

CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
    Brisbane\DC3 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:55:31 was successful.
    Brisbane\MX1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 579be28b-006e-4f1c-911a-780458c5d081
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:55:31 was successful.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain
    Brisbane\DC3 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:55:31 was successful.
    Brisbane\MX1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 579be28b-006e-4f1c-911a-780458c5d081
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:55:31 was successful.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
    Brisbane\DC3 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:55:31 was successful.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=corp,DC=domain
    Brisbane\DC3 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 232f1e47-aa8e-44ae-8a19-6e1e5ecd6346
        Last attempt @ 2013-03-19 14:55:31 was successful.
```

---

### repadmin /replsummary

```
Replication Summary Start Time: 2013-03-19 14:59:31

Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:
  ......


Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC2                       12m:51s    0 /   8    0  
 DC3                       12m:51s    0 /   8    0  
 MX1                       11m:11s    0 /   6    0  


Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC2                       04m:00s    0 /   8    0  
 DC3                       11m:11s    0 /   8    0  
 MX1                       12m:51s    0 /   6    0
```

---

### repadmin /kcc

```
Repadmin: running command /kcc against full DC localhost
Brisbane
Current Site Options: (none)
Consistency check on localhost successful.
```

---

### Netdom -query fsmo

```
Schema master               DC2.corp.domain
Domain naming master        DC2.corp.domain
PDC                         DC2.corp.domain
RID pool manager            DC2.corp.domain
Infrastructure master       DC2.corp.domain
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "local"? Do you mean if there is no GC in the same site as the Exchange server?

Comment: Good question. I should word that better. I mean local in the sense that the server is a DC with a global catalogue. If I don't have the global catalogue on the server or I change the domain controller exchange uses it stops authentication working.

Comment: Could you please run some diagnostic on your AD?
http://rays-it.blogspot.ca/2012/03/performing-and-active-directory-health.html

Comment: ok here are some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange 2010 servers requires a domain controller with a GC in the same site.

Also, running Exchange on a domain controller is not recommended. And you definitely can't promote an Exchange server to a domain controller.

It sounds like from your description you broken at least two of these rules, if not all three.

Answer (score 0):

Solution offered by [ashdrewness](http://www.reddit.com/user/ashdrewness)

---

It's not supported to run dcpromo on a server after exchange is installed. It's also not supported to do an in-place upgrade from std to ent with exchange installed. You have to uninstall exchange or perform a disaster recovery install of exchange (setup.com /recoverserver).

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719(v=exchg.141).aspx

> Installing Exchange 2010 on Directory Servers
>
> For security and performance reasons, we recommend that you install Exchange 2010 only on member servers and not on Active Directory directory servers. However, you can't run DCPromo on a computer running Exchange 2010. After Exchange 2010 is installed, changing its role from a member server to a directory server, or vice versa, isn't supported.